# How to disable other Checkboxes on click (AlertBuilder)

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

So, I have this code to show a `MultiChoiceItem`, however these items also include a option "Always" and "Never". If one of them is selected, all other checkboxes should be disabled (or enabled if the option is unchecked again).

The problem is, how can I actually access the checkboxes? As far as I am concerned, they don't have an ID either, so I can't access them with `findViewById()` (or do they?)

The code I am using for the popup is below, although you probably don't need it.

And just to visualize it, I added a screenshot as well. So in case "Always" is clicked, the method should gray out all other items, but leave the checked state.

Thanks!

[image]

```
private void createPopup(boolean[] selected) {
    final CharSequence[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cb_Entries);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.l_active));
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, selected, new OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
            stateSelectedItems[which] = isChecked;
        }
    });

    builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.b_okay), dialogListener);
    builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.b_cancel), dialogListener);
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

/edit: So, thanks to littleFluffyKitty, I am able to gray out the checkboxes, but they are still clickable (and change their values!), even when `setClickable(false)` is used.

That is the code I use:

```
popUpDialog.getListView().getChildAt(i).setEnabled(enable);
```

Answer (score 0):

The AlertDialog class has a method called [getListView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#getListView%28%29).  With that you can get access to the ListView which holds the checkable options.  From there you, since you know the order of the list, you can get the rows you want and then setEnabled(false) on them;

Comment: Interestingly, the chexboxes *are* grayed out, but I can still change the value by clicking on them. Any ideas?

Comment: I found out, that I have to overwrite the method `isEnabled` frome the ListAdapter. How can I do that?

Comment: @Force, what about setting setEnabled(false) and setClickable(false) and (if it is available) setCheckable(false)?

Comment: No, I already tried that. I can't use `setCheckable` or `isChecked` either, as it is just the child view, not the Checkbox itself.